# Errors while working with OpenCV 2.4.1

Tags: image-processing, opencv, object-recognition

I have delphi-7 wrappers for opencv.

I have the following errors while executing certain OpenCV methods:

```
cvPyrDown - error: External exception E06D7363.
    main thread ($1e24):
    7c812afb +000052 kernel32.dll                               RaiseException
    008af8ec +00004c MSVCR90D.dll                               _CxxThrowException
    1022d1bd +226673 opencv_core241d.dll                        ?    error@cv@@YAXABVException@1@@Z
    00ae084b +1aba11 opencv_imgproc241d.dll                     cvPyrDown
    0049a3f6 +00013e TestProject.exe        OpenCV_Test  93 +23 FindSquares

cvSetImageCOI: error: External exception E06D7363.
    main thread ($192c):
    7c812afb +000052 kernel32.dll                            RaiseException
    008af8ec +00004c MSVCR90D.dll                            _CxxThrowException
    1022d1bd +226673 opencv_core241d.dll                     ?error@cv@@YAXABVException@1@@Z
    1006572c +06235a opencv_core241d.dll                     cvSetImageCOI
    0049a410 +000160 TestProject.exe     OpenCV_Test  99 +29 FindSquares
```

What is wrong or can be wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. There was the problem with number of image channells in the destination image.